# Why doesn't `std::initializer_list` provide a subscript operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, operator-overloading, initializer-list

Suppose that you are writing a function that accepts an `std::initializer_list` called `list`, and that the function requires random access to `list`'s elements. It would be convenient to write `list[i]` instead of `list.begin()[i]`. So why doesn't `std::initializer_list` provide a definition of `operator[]`?

I can't think of any cases where an `operator[]` returning `const T&` would not be well-defined. Efficiency doesn't seem to be the issue here, since `std::initializer_list<T>::iterator` is aliased to `const T*`, which is clearly a random-access iterator.

Comment: I would guess because its prime use-case is to be a list that is sequentially processed.

Comment: A common use case is for a constructor that allocates a block of memory and constructs the elements in the block using `allocator.construct(p, v)`. While the list is still sequentially processed, the outer for-loop already has a counter which lends itself to the `operator[]` syntax.

Comment: @void-pointer Wouldn’t you normally *copy* in these circumstances? That way you don’t need a loop, and I’d generally avoid an explicit loop anyway. The question is still valid, though.

Comment: @void-pointer: You can just write that loop with iterators too, and surely there are some algorithms you can use too

Comment: @KonradRudolph Good point, `uninitialized_copy` would do the job more elegantly. Brb, have to refactor some code =)

Comment: As a guess, first iteration in the standard.  Keep it simple?  Amusingly, `.begin()[N]` works if `begin` is random.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to Bjarne Stroustrup in Section 17.3.4.2 (p. 497) of The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition:

> Unfortunately, initializer_list doesn't provide subscripting.

No further reason is given.

My guess is that it's one of these reasons:

1. it's an omission, or
2. because the initializer_list class is implemented with an array and you'd have to do bounds checking to provide safe access, it could more easily be used unsafely if that interface was provided, or
3. to be consistent with the std algorithms iteration paradigm, or
4. because initializer_lists are, by their nature, ad-hoc, there's more room for error by addressing them directly

2 and 4 sound kind of weak. as does 3. My money's on 1.

Comment: 6 years later, do we know the answer?

Comment: @jippyjoe4 Now 9! :)

Answer (score 7):

It's indeed a bit annoying, not having square brackets operator for std::initializer_list, as the need for random direct access for a specific index is a reasonable scenario.

However, this ability can be added with some simple code:

```
// the class _init_list_with_square_brackets provides [] for initializer_list
template<class T>
struct _init_list_with_square_brackets {
    const std::initializer_list<T>& list;
    _init_list_with_square_brackets(const std::initializer_list<T>& _list): list(_list) {}
    T operator[](unsigned int index) {
        return *(list.begin() + index);
    } 
};

// a function, with the short name _ (underscore) for creating 
// the _init_list_with_square_brackets out of a "regular" std::initializer_list
template<class T>
_init_list_with_square_brackets<T> _(const std::initializer_list<T>& list) {
    return _init_list_with_square_brackets<T>(list);
}
```

Now we have a new global function named _ (underscore) which is probably not a good name for a global C++ method, unless we want to create some "undescore-like" utility lib for C++, which will have its own namespace, overloading the _ function for all sort of other useful usages.

The new _ function can be used now like this:

```
void f(std::initializer_list<int> list) {
    cout << _(list)[2]; // subscript-like syntax for std::initializer_list!
}

int main() {
    f({1,2,3}); // prints: 3
    cout << _({1,2,3})[2]; // works also, prints: 3
    return 0;
}
```

It is to be noted that the solution provided above is not a good bargain in terms of performance if you run over many items of std::initializer_list, as a temporary object of the suggested type above `_init_list_with_square_brackets` is created repeatedly. Which again of course raises the wonder why this was not provided by the standard itself.

Comment: That's nice. An alternative, hijacking @Yakk's comment on the question, is "auto mylist = list.begin()" and then mylist[n] works.

Comment: If I would see syntax in a code I would immediately be "wtf". I would be clueless that `_` is actually an id, less denoting a function. Like rly, "wtf". I would probably figure it out eventually (does "go to definition" work for an id named `_` ??) , but that won't do anything to alleviate my intense, rapid and repeated mentions of the family of the coder that wrote that. My advice just go with `list.begin()[i]`. I am sorry to downvote because it's a cool trick, language-wise, but in practice it will backfire.

Comment: I guess you actually want to return a `cons T&` instead of a copy.

Comment: @bolov the original wtf is the omission. people will never return to cpp with such hickups.