# Inline array declaration with direct access in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, inline

I would like to do a stuff like this in c++ :

```
for (int i = 0, i < 3; ++i)
{
   const auto& author = {"pierre", "paul", "jean"}[i];
   const auto& age = {12, 45, 43}[i];
   const auto& object = {o1, o2, o3}[i];
   print({"even", "without", "identifier"}[i]);
   ...
}
```

Does everyone know how to do this kind of trick ? I do it a lot in python.
It helps me to factorize code nicely.

Comment: That looks like ... a bad idea? Why whould you construct an array every loop iteration just then to get a different element each time? What's wrong with declaring `authors={"friedrich johann", "wolfgang", "martin"};` outside the loop first, and then in the loop just pick `const auto &author=authors[i];`?

Comment: You've right, that's the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should have used a vector of your custom class with `author`, `age`, `object` and `whatever` attributes, put it in a vector and do range for-loop over it - that would be idiomatic in C++:

```
struct foo
{
    std::string author;
    int age;
    object_t object;
    whatever_t whatever;
};

std::vector<foo> foos = { /* contents */ };

for(auto const& foo : foos)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

If you really want to, you can do:

```
const auto author = std::vector<std::string>{"pierre", "paul", "jean"}[i];
//        ^ not a reference
```

but I'm not sure how well this will be optimised. You could also declare those vectors before the loop and keep the references.

Comment: The problem with range for-loop comes when you have many arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an object like `{"pierre", "paul", "jean"}` results in a initializer list. Initializer list does not have any [] operator [Why doesn't `std::initializer_list` provide a subscript operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787394/why-doesnt-stdinitializer-list-provide-a-subscript-operator). So you should convert to `const auto& author = (std::vector<std::string>{"pierre", "paul", "jean"})[i];`. Also the reference symbol should not be there as you are creating a temporary object and you are storing a reference to a temporary.