# Returning a value from an initializer list

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer-list

I have a switch statement which returns a value based on an index provided.

```
switch (index) {
  case 0: 
    return arr_1[index];
  case 1: 
    return arr_2[index];
  // and so on
}
```

Instead of using "arr_1" or "arr_2", i want to write something like:

```
switch (index) {
  case 0: 
    return {1, 2, 3}[index];
  case 1: 
    return {10, 45, 199}[index];
  // and so on
}
```

Is something like this possible?

**EDIT:**

Things I have tried:

- `int X(int x) { return {1, 2, 3, 4}[x]; }`
- `int X(int x) { static_cast<std::array<int, 4>> ({1, 2, 3, 4})[x]; }`
- `int X(int x) { return (int[])({1, 2, 3, 4})[x]; }`

Comment: Unless you want to return a reference to the array position so you can change it outside the function, it looks like it would be simpler to return always 1 for case 0 and return 45 for case 1

Comment: _Is something like this possible_ what did observe when you ran that code? What have you tried?

Comment: These are UI layout constants, all integers which are not modified outside the scope. They are static const ints

Comment: Someone just posted the answer with the correct expression which worked. But its now deleted. If posted again, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @lightalchemist why did you delete your post?

Comment: I am not sure how is this useful? In each array, only one element is used - the one that matches the index. Rest of the constants are never used.

Comment: Agreed.  if `index` is 0 then `1` is always returned, if `index` is 1 then `45` is always returned, and so on. Best to just hard-code that, eg: `switch (index) { case 0: return 1; case 1: return 45;   // and so on }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually can use an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for this. Something like the following should work:

```
int idx = 0;
std::cout << std::array<int, 3>{1, 2, 3}[idx] << "\n";
```

Sadly, this is quite verbose. Here is a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int testFunction()
{
    int index = 0;
    switch (index)
    {
    case 0:
        return std::array<int, 3>{1, 2, 3}[index];
    case 1:
        return std::array<int, 3>{10, 45, 199}[index];
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << testFunction() << "\n";
}
```

If [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) implemented an indexing operator, then your snippet may have worked. If you really want to use an initializer list, however, then you can use the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

using inl = std::initializer_list<int>;

int testFunction()
{
    int index = 0;
    switch (index)
    {
    case 0:
        return (inl{1, 2, 3}.begin())[index];
    case 1:
        return (inl{10, 45, 199}.begin())[index];
    }
}
```

I don't recommend this, since it is unclear in comparison to the first implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of template magic and everyone is happier without cumbersome template parameters. This is IMO more elegant and easier to use:

```
#include <array>

template<class T, class ...Args>
struct first_arg{
    using type = T;
};

template<class ...Args>
using first_arg_t = typename first_arg<Args...>::type;

template<class ...Args>
auto lst(Args &&...args){
    return std::array<first_arg_t<Args...>, sizeof...(Args)>({ std::forward<Args>(args)... });
}

int main(){
    const auto a = lst(1, 2, 3, 4)[2];
    return 0;
}
```

I know it does not explicitly use initializer list, but it seems like best answer to Your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return / access a value from the [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) by index as the `std::initializer_list` [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787394/why-doesnt-stdinitializer-list-provide-a-subscript-operator) provide a subscript operator nor a member function allowing you to access element by index. Use the container that does implement a subscript operator such as [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or similar.